# Como podría simular en python la función de Excel: sumar.si.conjunto( )

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

les agradecería me pudieran ayudar con esta duda.

Como podría simular en python la función `sumar.si.conjunto()` de excel.

Tengo un archivo (*.csv*) al cual accedo con un Dataframe en python. Debo crear una columna que simule el comportamiento de la función: `sumar.si.conjunto()`.

Adjunto una imagen del proceso que realizo en una planilla de excel. **Cabe señalar que los criterios de rango se encuentran en la misma columna de rango.**

[image: Proceso realizado en una planilla de excel]

Comment: podrías colocar el código que llevas? Estas trabajando con pandas?

Comment: Es que el dato lo exporto con ````producible = pd.read_csv(archivo.csv)````, luego necesito crear una columna como indica la imgen con la función: sumar.si.conjunto()

Comment: 1. no lo exportas, lo *importas* 2. podrías explicarme que hace la función `contar.si.conjunto()`?? no sé Excel >_<

Comment: En el contexto de mi pregunta: Imagina que es un tipo de groupby, donde suma los valores de la columna "K" según el criterio de las columnas "G", "H", "I" y "J". Dicho criterio es dinamico a medida que te mueves por las filas.

Comment: No entiendo esa función, por lo que no daré una respuesta que pueda estar equivocada, lo siento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO es una suma condicionada en Excel. Implica sumar todos los valores de una misma columna, siempre y cuando se cumplan criterios en otras columnas diferentes. Un ejemplo sencillo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imaginemos que queremos saber, por ejemplo, cuando dinero se ha gastado Juan. Pues lo que queremos es sumar la columna IMPORTE, pero solo aquellas filas que en la columna PERSONA el valor sea Juan, siendo la respuesta 55.

Se puede aplicar más de un criterio: por ejemplo. ¿Cuánto dinero se ha gastado JUAN en GAS? Pues es lo mismo que antes, sumar la columna IMPORTE pero solo aquellas filas que la columna PERSONA sea igual a Juany la columna GASTO sea igual a Gas.

Ahora en Python, como no has proporcionado datos de ejemplo, he utilizado el dataset de Iris de la librería seaborn y me he inventado una fórmula en Excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi fórmula en Excel es:
`=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($A$2:$A$151;$E$2:$E$151;E2;$C$2:$C$151;C2)`

Es decir, quiero sumar la columna SEPAL.LENGTH pero en cada fila solo quiero la suma de SEPAL.LENGTH de aquellas filas que tengan el mismo PETAL_LENGTH y VARIETY que la propia fila. Y quiero aplicarlo a todas las filas.

Pues en Python yo lo haría usando listas: creo listas de cada columna que uso como criterio, así como de la que quiero sumar. Y mediante *list_comprehesion* me construyo una lista nueva con el resultado calculado usando la propiedad LOC de los dataframes. Y luego añado la lista al dataframe y listo:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

lista_criterio1 = list(df["species"])
lista_criterio2 = list(df["petal_length"])

sumar_si_conjunto = [df.loc[(df['species'] == lista_criterio1[i]) & (df['petal_length'] ==lista_criterio2[i]),"sepal_length"].sum() for i in range(df.shape[0])]

df["sumar_si_conjunto"]=sumar_si_conjunto
df
```

Y obtengo el siguiente output:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si comparamos lo que obtenemos con Python y lo que obtenemos con Excel, veremos que coincide perfectamentE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias por tu asertiva y academica respuesta. Entendí muy bien el ejercicio y lo apliqué a mi problema en especifico y funcionó.