# Suma producto en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Quisiera saber si es posible realizar de alguna manera la suma de los productos de un archivo de Excel en Python?

Ya lo intente multiplicando y sumando pero no funciona de la misma manera, quisiera saber si se puede de alguna manera realizarlo como la función de suma producto en Excel?

Comment: Si se puede, pero seria de ayuda si colocas lo que has intentado. Lee [ask]

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar la estructura de tu archivo y lo que has intentado para resolverlo? Recuerda que es recomendable incluir un [mcve], de otro modo tu pregunta probablemente temrine cerrada. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta enm cualquier momento.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/476609/como-podr%c3%ada-simular-en-python-la-funci%c3%b3n-de-excel-sumar-si-conjunto ahí explica cómo simular un SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO. Tú quieres SUMAPRODUCTO que es diferente, pero en vez de sumar, multiplica y luego sumas todos los resultados de dichas multiplicaciones.